# Prevent software installation for Domain Users

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

Please, I was wondering how may can I block normal Domain Users from installing software but I can install using Administrators accounts (it's just like needs elevation before install) using GPO's?

I have already tried the Windows Installer policy but it disallow all users from installation including Admins!

using GPMC ==> administrative TEmplates==> Windows Components ==> Windows Installer ==> Prohibt Windows Installer ==> Enabled

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior?

Comment: Windows Installer policy is not effective for applications that don't use Windows Installer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Enterprise edition of Windows, you can implement [AppLocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview), specifically [Windows Installer rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/windows-installer-rules-in-applocker).

However, users without admin privileges can, by default, only install software on their user account (not computer-wide).

Comment: This may help but it does far more than just blocking software installations. But I would recommend it to lock down the system.